# Decrypting Apple VAS Data received

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography, nfc, passkit

I have sending data from NFC Pass to POS terminal where i have included encryptionPublicKey. I have been trying to decrypt the Apple VAS only Data received on NFC POS terminal.
i am not aware of these encryption and decryption processes.
Can anyone help on this to decrypt the data received?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Apple's VAS protocol to get the decrypted data along with following their decryption steps, which are under NDA, to decrypt the returned data. Sorry I could not be more help.

I work for [PassNinja](https://passninja.com), we are trying to make this process easier for developers for NFC enabled Apple and Google Wallet passes.

Answer (score 0):

Public key goes into the pass.  Private key goes into the terminal or your payments app.